# Questions about some projects in android source

Tags: android-source

I am new in android open source project(AOSP) . I want to know about some of its projects : Anyone can describe these projects and what is its role in android OS?

- Libcore
- Developers/build
- Developers/demos
- Developers/samples/android
- PDK
- Platform_testing
- Toolchain/binutils
- Bootable/recovery
- Build/blueprint
- Build/kati
- Build/soong
- Device/common
- Device/generic/***
- External / ***
- Framework / ***
- Hardware / ***
- Prebuilts / ***
- System / ***
- Tools/external/fat32lib
- Tools/external/gradel
- Tools/test/connectivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libcore - android device runtime java environment

PDK - platfrom developer kit

bootable/recovery - recovery partition program

bootable/bootloader/ - bootloader partition program (including fastboot device driver ie. u-boot on TI or IMX platforms or aboot on MSM/APQ)

device - device vendor additional mk files and overlay files External - a set of any 3rd party libs and programs (it's mainly open source projects)

framework - android framework implementation. This code is what android apps calls. This where all services and their libs are.

hardware - hardware modules defined by android and implemented    by device/hardware provider (people like Qcom, TI, NXP, Nvidia etc...)

vendors - HAL layer code for many hardware

prebuilts - gcc and other binary tools (excluding java sdk) you use to compile that version of android you have downloaded/"repo sync'ed"

system - initd daemon and base system C libraries

bionic - android version of standard c library and runtime loader and linker code.